# RSpec stubs apparently not cleaned up after test

Tags: ruby, rspec

I've been working to diagnose a test failure that only occurs on my master branch.  Following is the relevant code, in simplified form.

There's a service:

```
class Service

  attr_reader :traces

  def initialize
    @traces = []
  end

  def do_work
    @traces << Thread.current.backtrace
    # ... actual work ...
  end

end
```

And a class that makes use of the service:

```
class Widget

  def get_cached_service
    puts("Getting a cached service!")
    puts("Do I already have one? #{!!@service}")
    @service ||= make_service
  end

  def make_service
    puts("Making a service!")
    Service.new
  end

end
```

I have a test (that lives in a file `widget_spec.rb`) that fails intermittently.  This test creates an instance of `Widget` and calls `get_cached_service`.  I see the `Getting a cached service!` message on the console, followed by `Do I already have one? false`, but I *don't* see the `Making a service!` message.

Furthermore, when I examine the `traces` attribute of the returned `Service` object, I find stack traces originating from *other tests in my project* (eg. `foo_spec.rb`, `bar_spec.rb`, etc).

In a few different places I find code like:

```
allow_any_instance_of(Widget)
  .to receive(:make_service).and_return(whatever)
```

The other tests whose stack traces I find are likely stubbing `make_service` like this.  But it appears that the stubbing is not being undone after those tests, as should always happen according to my understanding.

Is there any reason, other than a bug in rspec, that could cause a stub not to be reset at the end of a test?

Comment: It very well might be an _rspec-mocks_ bug. From the [README](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks#settings-mocks-or-stubs-on-any-instance-of-a-class), it states in regard to **allow_any_instance_of** - `It is the most complicated feature of rspec-mocks, and has historically received the most bug reports. (None of the core team actively use it, which doesn't help.)`

Answer (score 0):

The stub is almost certainly being cleared, but you’ve cached the fake instance in `get_cached_service`. Nothing clears the cached value in `@service`, and RSpec (rightfully) doesn’t know about it. As such, stubbing `make_service` is not enough if tests call `get_cached_service`. You have a few options:

- Always stub `get_cached_service` instead of, or in addition to, `make_service`
- Provide a way to clear the cached value which is called after each test.
- Make the caching configurable in some way, or a wrapper around the actual implementation, such that the caching does not occur in test code.

Comment: I've updated the question to add that I have checked whether the value is cached beforehand, and it's not.  In any case, in my `widget_spec.rb` I explicitly create a new object with `Widget.new`, so whatever might have been cached in a Widget instance in some other test can't possibly still be cached in the Widget spec, unless there are RSpec shenanigans happening that are similar to what I've described.

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is quite late to answer, but for posterity for anyone who reads this:

Use rspec bisect to figure out if there is a consistent test ordering that causes failure, then start ripping code out until you're left with only the bit that breaks.

I can't remember a case where RSpec is at fault - almost invariably, somewhere there is a class variable that isn't getting cleared, or someone is manually playing with a class with something like `define_method`. Occasionally it might be happening in a gem.

Make sure everything is cleared after every test in your spec_helper - clear the Rails cache, clear ActionMailer deliveries, return from Timecop freezes, etc.

Anything directly RSpec-related should clear itself in theory, because it's designed to integrate into RSpec, and is probably the least likely explanation in general.